# symfony 1.4 - change Sluggable options

Tags: symfony-1.4

I need to remove a dash from the Sluggable field. But it is needed only for  Company table, as there are another tables that use this option, I do not want to change them. So if I insert "ABC Studio", I need to get "ABCStudio".
Now I get "abs-studio"

```
Company:
  actAs:
    Timestampable:
    Sluggable:
      fields: [name]
      canUpdate: true
```

Answer (score 0):

`Sluggable` has option named builder, which is by default set to `('Doctrine_Inflector', 'urlize')` - that is, `Doctrine_Inflector::urlize($text)` is called. You can set it to your own:

```
Company:
  actAs:
    Timestampable:
    Sluggable:
      fields: [name]
      canUpdate: true
      builder: [CompanyTable, urlize]
```